# Hide specific shipping methode depending on day and time of day

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to further expand the code given here: [Hide specific shipping method depending on day time in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946611/hide-specific-shipping-method-depending-on-day-time-in-woocommerce)

This snippet will, depending on the time of day, hide a specific shipping method, and it works. But I would also like to include the current day.

For example: get the current day and time, and if you are ordering on saturday (= today) after 11pm, you can no longer select the saturday delivery option. If ordering on saturday (= today) before 11pm, you can still select it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_time', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_time( $rates, $package )
{
    // Set your default time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    
    // Here set your shipping rate Id
    $shipping_rate_id = 'local_pickup:13';

    // When this shipping method is available and after 11 AM
    if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id, $rates ) && date('H') > 11 ) {
        unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id]); // remove it
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: What is the *saturday delivery option*? The "vanilla" WooCommerce does not allow to choose delivery date/time for the order.

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky I have multiple delivery options they can choose from - like local pickup, delivery on saturday, delivery on sonday, etc. But I want to disable certain options based on day and time. The above snippet is only for time.

Comment: There was a typo in original answer (`&` instead of `&&`), fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current day of week you can use the `date('w')` function call (complete format description can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). The whole condition to exclude the shipping method, say *it is saturday and over 11 o'clock*, can be written as

```
date('w') == 6 && date('H') > 11
```

and the whole `if` block would be

```php
    if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id, $rates ) && date('w') == 6 && date('H') > 11 ) {
        unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id]); // remove the shipping method
    }
```

You are using the `'local_pickup:13'` shipping method id as shown in the example you are referring to, but you'd need to find an actual shipping method id for your particular case.